# Assigning a UITabBarController as the RootNavigationController

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, storyboard

I am currently using XCode 4.3 and storyboards. I have 3 `ViewControllers` in my `RootTabBarController`. I want my `SecondViewController` to be a `RootNavigationController` so I can derive into other screens from that. Any ideas how can I achieve it via interface builder or programmatically.

***NOTE:***
I tried to pull in a Navigation Controller(which comes with its root controller, and I tried to assign the `SecondViewController` as the `RootNavigationController`, which failed as I suspected, since `TabBarController` has a root relation with it.

Comment: The comments in the answer imply that this question is abandoned and will not get updated with a meaningful solution.  It should probably be withdrawn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly you want the root view controller of your app to be a tab bar controller and for the app to start on the second tab.

```
self.window.rootViewController = myTabBarController;
myTabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;
```

Comment: Actually I have a RootViewController on my app, where I used at my login screens. Im ashamed I am asking this, but should there be only one navigation root controller, or can I add multiple of them?

Comment: you should edit in some code (how you set up your view controllers) or a better description to your question because it is really hard to understand right now. I also think you are getting some of the terminology confused, which is furthering the problem. There is no such thing is a root navigation controller (at least not built in). There is a root viewcontroller for your application, and then there are navigation controllers (one of which could be your root viewcontroller).

Comment: Yeah, you are right. My approach and usage of navigation controller was simply not right, which lead this problem. Thanks a lot for pointing that out. And apparently I should look deeper in usage of navigation controllers...

Comment: the apple docs will give you a good outline of it so that would be a good place to start. good luck!